# SeekBar not update and Toast.makeTake don't stop when exit app

Tags: android, seekbar, android-alertdialog

I create app to change TextSize by use SeekBar in Dialog Alert. When i use seekBar TextSize will change and show font number by Toast. But, when dialog Dismiss. Toast still work and Increase show number. It's not stop and continue operate when i perss home or exit app . Where am i wrong. How can I fix this. Code's be simple. Thank a lot for erveryone.

Here my code.

```
    public void ShowDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final SeekBar seek = new SeekBar(this);

    seek.setMax(100);

    popDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.conp);
    popDialog.setTitle(R.string.menu_settings);
    popDialog.setView(seek);

    seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {

            subtitles.setTextSize(progress);

            Toast.makeText(ShowMan.this, "your textsize :" + String.valueOf(progress), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    // Button
    popDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    popDialog.create();
    popDialog.show();

}
```

I want to use this SeekBar Increase & Decrease TextSize normally. Please help me.
Oh... one more thing. My Teacher say "don't use dialog theme". T_T

Comment: Where have you written ShowDialog method.Please paste complete code.

Comment: I create ImageView btngo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnSetting);    btngo.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener()                    public void onClick(View v) {                                              ShowDialog();                                                         });

Answer (score 0):

You can give toast `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` or give a **milisecond** use like below `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT="some value"`

```
 Toast.makeText(ShowMan.this, "your textsize :" + String.valueOf(progress), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 Toast.makeText(ShowMan.this, "your textsize :" + String.valueOf(progress), 2000).show();
```

Comment: not work again. progress is still count when dialog dismiss & exit.